# reading the html code, how to know if something is going to be downloaded?

Tags: html

I have access to the HTML code of a page, and I need to know which tags I can check to know if something is going to be downloaded?

For example, is there any pdf in the page, any big pictures, a video on the page, I'd need to block them through a proxy before I load the page.

What I use exactly : a proxy through C#, I can get the html before loading the page.

Comment: There aren't any specific tags for downloading files. I think your best bet is to search for file extensions (.pdf, .jpg, .zip, .exe, ...)

Answer (score 1):

With standard html, you can check tags such as `A`, `IMG`, `VIDEO`, `OJECT`, `EMBED`, sometimes you'll need to watch for the `src` attribute, sometimes it's `href`...

In other pages, sometimes you should validate a `form`, than you'll be redirected to the download.

With new kind of application, download can be trigger by javascript listners as `onclick`, `onsubmit`, `mouseup`, ....

Well, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Images will be downloaded, as will js, and css files. A PDF won't as it need a user interaction to initial the download from the server.

It would help if you could let us know what you're trying to achieve.

M

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the inspector on Chrome to check what assets will be downloaded. It's located under the `Network` tab

[image]